# Stop playing audio if user answered call

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have a player application that can play music in background.
I'm using **AVAudioSessionDelegate** to implement methods `- (void)beginInterruption` and `- (void)endInterruption` but I don't know how to determine if user answered on call or he didn't. If he answered on call I don't want to resume playing music, but if he didn't I want to resume it.

Answer (score 0):

This picture should summarize the answer to your question:[image]

So, basically, you can disable audio in `applicationWillResignActive:`. If the call is not answered, you can resume playing audio in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Actually, in order to avoid some disruption in your audio playing, you might also try and disable audio in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, but the suggested way is the one described above.

Comment: My application should work in background, and the only time when i need to disable audio is when interruption occurs. I read [this documentation](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW3) but didn't understand how to determine if user answered on call or he didn't. I tried to use `AudioSessionGetProperty()` function to check `kAudioSessionProperty_InterruptionType` property, but it gave me the same value in both situations.

Comment: Have you tried using `– endInterruptionWithFlags:` in AVAudioSessionDelegate? it will tell you if you can resume playing or not...

Comment: According [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Interruption_Flags) documentation `-endInterruptionWithFlags:` returning only one value `AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume`, so it will not help to me =(